# Position(t) on cubic bezier curve

Tags: math, bezier, cubic-spline

The only equation to calculate this that I can find involves `t` in the range [0, 1], but I have no idea how long it will take to travel the entire path, so I can't calculate `(1 - t)`.

I know the speed at which I'm traveling, but it seems to be a heavy idea to calculate the total time beforehand (nor do I actually know how to do that calculation). What is an equation to figure out the position without knowing the total time?

**Edit** To clarify on the cubic bezier curve: I have four control points (P0 to P1), and to get a value on the curve with t, I need to use the four points as such:

`B(t) = (1-t)^3P0 + 3t(1-t)^2P1 + 3t^2(1-t)P2 + t^3P3`

I am not using a parametric equation to define the curve. The control points are what define the curve. What I need is an equation that does not require the use of knowing the range of `t`.

Comment: Is it related to programming?

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a misunderstanding here. The 't' in the cubic Bezier curve's definition does not refer to 'time'. It is parameter that the x, y or even z functions based on. Unlike the traditional way of representing y as a function of x, such as y=f(x), an alternative way of representing a curve is by the parametric form that represents x, y and z as functions of an additional parameter t, C(t)=(x(t), y(t), z(t)). Typically the t value will range from 0 to 1, but this is not a must. The common representation for a circle as x=cos(t) and y=sin(t) is an example of parametric representation. So, if you have the parametric representation of a curve, you can evaluate the position on the curve for any given t value. It has nothing to do with the time it takes to travel the entire path.

Comment: I do understand that it doesn't necessarily refer to time, but if I want to evaluate it with time (as that is the only changing variable I have) then I'm lost--I know it doesn't have to range from 0 to 1, but I don't know the range at all. I only know the single t value. The only equation I can find to give me a position at some variable t involves knowing the range of t. Is there an equation that does not?

Comment: When using paramatric representation, the range of t is used to limit the extent of the curve. It will not affect how the position is evaluated. For example, C(t)=(cos(t), sin(t)) with t=0~PI/4 describes a 90 degree circular arc, instead of a full circle. The point on the 90 degree arc is still evaluated by cos and sin functions, which is exactly the same as how a full circle is evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

You have the given curve and you have your speed. To calculate what you're asking for you need to divide the total distance by the speed you traveled given that time. That will give you the parametric (t) you need. So if the total curve has a distance of 72.2 units and your speed is 1 unit then your t is 1/72.2.

Your only missing bit is calculating the length of a given curve. This is typically done by subdividing it into line segments small enough that you don't care, and then adding up the total distance of those line segments. You could likely combine those two steps as well if you were so inclined. If you have your given speed, just iteration like 1000th of the curve add the line segment between the start and point 1000th of the way through the curve, and subtract that from how far you need to travel (given that you have speed and time, you have distance you need to travel), and keep that up until you've gone as far as you need to go.

The range for t is between 0 and 1.

```
        x = (1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)*p0x + 3*(1-t)*(1-t)*t*p1x + 3*(1-t)*t*t*p2x + t*t*t*p3x;
        y = (1-t)*(1-t)*(1-t)*p0y + 3*(1-t)*(1-t)*t*p1y + 3*(1-t)*t*t*p2y + t*t*t*p3y;
```

[image]